# Efficiency of Python TCP socket recv(1) vs recv(n)

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I'm building a TCP application which uses a newline `\n` to separate messages of unknown length (but typically < 64 bytes).  I'm finding [this article](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/05/18/code-sample-socket-client-thread-in-python/) to be very useful.

Is the best (i.e. most efficient / fastest) approach to `recv` one character at a time and check if its a newline or `recv` a larger buffer and store "leftovers" in the class?

**One at a time**

```
def __recv_until_newline(self):
    message = ""
    while True:
        chunk = self.socket.recv(1)
        if chunk == "" or chunk == "\n":
            break
        message += chunk
    return message
```

**Maintain a buffer**

```
def __recv_until_newline(self):
    """ self.__buffer holds previously received message parts"""
    message = self.__buffer
    while True:
        chunk = self.socket.recv(64)
        message += chunk
        if chunk == "" or "\n" in message:
            break

    # something a bit more intelligent than this in reality, but you get the idea
    messages = message.split('\n')
    self.__buffer = "".join([x for x in message[1:]])
    return messages[0]
```

Comment: Also note that, your first version, has *quadratic* complexity. Every time you do `message += chunk` a *new* string object is created, which means the whole `message` is copied and the last byte added. If the messages are 64 bytes long, then the first loop would simply create a string of length 1, the second one has to copy the previous string and add 1 character, then you have to copy two characters and add an other, in the end you have a cost around `sum(range(64)) = 2016`, instead of only `64` with `recv(64)`. Using a `list` and `''.join` you can avoid this quadratic behaviour.

Comment: "chunk" is bytes.  Comparing it with "\n" should not make sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting big chunks is definitely more efficient simply because you are doing less operations. Think about it like this: if you have a message of length 1000, then your loop will fire 1000 times in first case and in second only 16. Performance loss is obvious. Of course this is because of Python, but even on OS level it is more efficient because of the same reason: making 1000 sys calls instad of 16. And scanning string (by the way: you should scan `chunk` instead of `message`) of length 64 is less expensive then 64 calls to `recv`. That's pretty much it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... kind of makes sense its just the implementation is a bit more messy :)